# Unable to parse config file 'nuget.config'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm getting the following error when attempting to "Manage NuGet packages" for a multi-project solution in Visual Studio 2015.
The same error also occurs when trying to manage the packages at a project level for all but two projects within the solution:

[image: Screenshot of VS error]

The content of the above mentioned file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\..\packages" />
  </config>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org (http)" />
    <add key="xxxxx NuGet Server" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org (http)" value="http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="xxxxx NuGet" value="\\10.180.1.119\xxxxx\NuGet" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="xxxxx  NuGet Server" value="http://10.141.129.81:9091/nuget" />
    <add key="Octopus Internal Feed" value="http://10.180.1.119:8081/nuget/packages" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="true" />
    <add key="Octopus Internal Feed" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>
```

After clicking OK on this error, nothing happens - it doesn't continue and thus doesn't allow me to make package changes.

However, if I open the solution in Visual Studio 2013, I don't get the error at all, and I can get into the package manager as expected:

[image: visual studio 2013 package manager]

Any help would be appreciated, as keeping and running VS2013 just to manage packages feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut :/

Answer (score 0):

## A parsing error means the format/syntax of the file is wrong.

To be more precise, it means that the current format/syntax of the file is not the expected format/syntax from the reader point of view.

### Why a parsing error could happen ?

- manual (error prone) change to the file.
- new version of the software which reads the file. (seems to be the root cause here)

### Pinpoint the problem

#### Fast way for small files

Comment incrementally parts of the file and check if the parsing error still occurs. 
By doing so wisely, you should be able to pinpoint what's wrong.

#### Long way but better

Read the documentation, learn the expected syntax and format, and then any parsing error would become obvious.

The problem is that current nuget documentation probably doesn't apply to visual studio 2015 (which is not supported anymore, ended on October 10th, 2017).

Use a supported version of Visual Studio (2017 or 2019) would be the recommended way to go.

#### Recreate the file with NuGet

NuGet can modify the configuration file in command line and even create a brand new file.

**For example:**

```
nuget config -set repositoryPath=..\..\..\packages -config NuGet.config
```

Comment: Which "newer version of visual studio" expects the nuget.config file to be that way? I ask, because this documentation (which I read and learnt as you suggest), states otherwise:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file